# How to run Capistrano task based on environment or server properties?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I have a namespace and a couple tasks in the namespace that run after deploy:updated. Here is an example:

```
namespace :myservice do
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      sudo :start, "my/application"
    end
  end
end
```

I'd love for one of these tasks to only run on a certain environment or host property. How can I accomplish this?

I'd love to be able to filter on environment such as:

```
namespace :myservice do
  task :start do
    on roles(:app), env(:vagrant) do
      sudo :start, "my/application"
    end
  end
end
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I never figured out how to do this and am no longer working with Capistrano.

Comment: @pjammer might be able to verify the answer below

Answer (score 1):

It seems like capistrano multi-stage would help you. https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension

Essentially, you would have a *stage* called `vagrant` where you might define configuration variables, which would then be referenced by your main `deploy.rb` script(s) and acted on.

Here is a conceptual example,

```
# config/deploy/production.rb
set :should_start_my_application, false


# config/deploy/vagrant.rb
set :should_start_my_application, true


# config/deploy.rb
namespace :myservice do
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      if should_start_application then
        sudo :start, "my/application"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to my old request. Unfortunately, I no longer do stuff with Ruby and Capistrano so I can't really test this. Do you think it makes sense to close my original question or just leave it open? I feel bad leaving it open indefinitely, especially since I hate seeing the same types of questions on stack overflow that linger forever.

Comment: No problem, and either closing or leaving it open works—but I am not 100% sure what works best for SO.

Comment: @pjammer might be able to verify the answer since he asked last month.

Comment: Minor correction - To use the variable `should_start_my_application`, we will have to fetch it in the rake task using `if fetch(:should_start_my_application) then...`